# Why doesn't Kotlin treat numbers as "Int" by default inside sumOf function lambda?

Tags: kotlin

In the below code:

```kotlin
val sum = listOf(1, 2, 3).sumOf { if (it % 2 == 0) 1 else 0 }
```

Kotlin gives the following error:

```
Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.sumOf(selector: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Int): Int defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.sumOf(selector: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Long): Long defined in kotlin.collections
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/ZD0SJEgVX)

If I explicitly use `toInt()`, the error is gone but I get a warning of redundant call

```kotlin
val sum = listOf(1, 2, 3).sumOf { if (it % 2 == 0) 1.toInt() else 0 }
```

Why doesn't Kotlin automatically use `Int` here?

Comment: Would you accept "because the spec says so" as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, but is there a solution where I don't get that redundant call warning?

Comment: This works and returns the same result: `val sum = listOf(1, 2, 3).sumOf { 1 - it % 2 }`. However, (1) I'm not quite sure why it works and the original doesn't; and (2) unfortunately this is not a general solution to your question.

Comment: @Sweeper, I'd love a brief explanation of what part of the spec is applicable. I would expect the expression `if (it % 2 == 0) 1 else 0` to unambiguously resolve to an Int.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks for the answer but the example I gave in the question is only a simplified version of my original problem. The list I have is a bit more complicated so `1 - it % 2` won't help there. What I have is like `list.sumOf { if(someCondition) x else y }` here x and y are usual integers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spec says the following about the [types of integer literals](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#the-types-for-integer-literals):

> A literal without the mark has a special integer literal type
> dependent on the value of the literal:
>
> - If the value is greater than maximum `kotlin.Long` value, it is an illegal integer literal and should be a compile-time error;
> - Otherwise, if the value is greater than maximum `kotlin.Int` value, it has type `kotlin.Long`;
> - Otherwise, it has an [integer literal type](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#integer-literal-types) containing all the built-in integer types guaranteed to be able to represent this value.

So integer literals like "1" doesn't have a simple type like `kotlin.Int` or `kotlin.Long`. It has an "integer literal type".

> Example: integer literal `0x01` has value 1 and therefore has type `ILT(kotlin.Byte,kotlin.Short,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Long)`. Integer literal 70000 has value 70000, which is not representable using types `kotlin.Byte` and `kotlin.Short` and therefore has type `ILT(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Long)`.

Here are the [subtyping rules](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#subtyping-for-integer-literal-types) of these ILTs. Importantly for your question:

```
∀Ti∈{T1,…,TK}:ILT(T1,…,TK)<:Ti
```

​
This rule basically says that ILTs work like an intersection type. For example, `ILT(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Long)` is a subtype of `kotlin.Int` and also a subtype of `kotlin.Long`.

Now let's look at your lambda `{ if (it % 2 == 0) 1 else 0 }`. It returns either the literal 0 or the literal 1. These both have the type:

```
ILT(kotlin.Byte,kotlin.Short,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Long)
```

which is a subtype of `kotlin.Long` and `kotlin.Int`. Therefore, your lambda can be converted to both a `(T) -> Long` and a `(T) -> Int`, in the same way that a `(T) -> Dog` can be converted to a `(T) -> Animal`.

When you use `toInt()`, then only the `(T) -> Int` overload matches the return type, since `Int` is not convertible to `Long` implicitly.

Apparently, if you do `toInt()` on the whole expression, there is no redundant `toInt` warning:

```
fun main() {
    val sum = listOf(1, 2, 3).sumOf { (if (it % 2 == 0) 1 else 0).toInt() }
}
```

Also note that the compiler looks at the lambda return type only because `sumOf` is annotated with [`OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-overload-resolution-by-lambda-return-type/). If not for this, you would still get an ambiguity error even if you use `toInt()`. See [Using lambda return type to refine function applicability](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#using-lambda-return-type-to-refine-function-applicability) for more info.

The reason why it is able to choose the `Int` overload in simple cases like:

```
fun foo(x: Int) {}
fun foo(x: Long) {}
fun main() { foo(43) }
```

is because of the "[Choosing the most specific candidate](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#algorithm-of-msc-selection)" step in overload resolution. In this step, it handles built in numeric types differently, and considers `Int` the "most specific". However, this step happens just before "Using lambda return type to refine function applicability", and thinks that `(T) -> Int` and `(T) -> Long` are equally specific.

Comment: Great answer! Note that `OverloadResolutionByLambdaReturnType` is marked as experimental; so, while it's not yet cast in stone, is it worth raising an issue about this? Also, note that while IntelliJ gives a redundancy warning on `1.toInt()`, it doesn't with `(1).toInt()`. But putting `toInt()` on the whole expression is, of course, better.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou [someone already did it, apparently](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46360/Type-inference-fails-to-infer-type-for-sumOf-call-with-constant-Overload-resolution-ambiguity-TypeVariableT-Int-Long) :-)